# What is this antique thing?

Tags: tool-identification

It's very light weight and folds nearly flat. My first thought is that it's a temporary holder for skeins of yarn used in a weaving factory. There was some kind of circular object tacked to one of the legs, maybe a label? The "shelves" are held up by cat-gut or some other natural cordage. The longest side is 24"

[image: Antique folding shelf?]

Comment: Are you asking after the object or the technique used to create it? In the first case - as it seems now - your question is off-topic, since it has nothing to do with creation or crafting. In the second case, please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: @Joachim, if you want this community to grow, you might want to be patient with new users and forgive their mistakes. How about suggesting which StackExchange community would be a better place to ask?

Comment: My apologies, I did not assume my tone to be antagonizing, nor your question to be a mistake - I was merely inquiring. You might want to try at [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/36552/), since, like you say, the object seems antique. (Interesting user name, by the way, it seems Frisian.)

Comment: @Tjalsma Very, very rarely is anyone on [crafts.se] intending to be anything but helpful. Comments are intended to ask for additional information, and because their length is necessarily brief, wording can be equally brief and to the point. I wouldn’t read anything into beside that, as designed, comments are meant to be short, clear, and not take much time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no reason to assume the object presented is a tool; there is no intent to fix or replicate it, or use it as a tool to create other things.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; so I [moved them chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98455/discussion-on-question-by-tjalsma-what-is-this-antique-thing) so we can stop pinging the OP but still discuss. Also, it's worth having a read [of our identification question policies](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/what-guidelines-should-we-set-for-identification-style-questions)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as a seemingly correct answer indicates, this is _not_ about a a crafting tool, as presumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a camel saddle. Numerous designs exist, for different camels & intended use (long riding trip, short ceremonial riding trip, pack animal, etc) and different regions. Some are made only for use as ottomans in houses, though! I remember the fashion for these was big in the 1970s. (I will never forget the one my piano teacher had near her grand piano in 1975, as she let me sit on it to wait, when my mom was late picking me up after my lesson)

One example: https://www.etsy.com/listing/603906532/old-camel-saddle-collectible-saddle

Comment: Excellent! just one question.  Does the camel's hump go between the saddle legs, or does each pair of legs fit over a hump?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 On a dromedary, the saddle goes on the hump. On a bactrian, I believe another version goes between the humps - but I am unable to find an online source to confirm! Image search on "camel saddle" and you'll see the incredible variety out there. I doubt there's one set rule. Again, I have no source, just what I have seen over the years of horse-packing and running into camels as pack animals, on the trail. (THAT was 'fun' the first time, with a skittish horse!)

Comment: @SueC thanks for solving the mystery!